# ASP.Net SQL ConnectionStrings config

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-express

I am trying to pick up ASP.Net - and following the mvc tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-4 (Note: I am totally new to the .Net framework, both C# and ASP.Net)

At the beginning the tutorial suggested to use SQL Server Compact 4.0 - But, I got the SQL Server Express installed instead (since I will be using it after, not just for the tutorial)

```
SELECT @@VERSION AS [Version]
```

`Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (Intel X86)   Apr  2 2010 15:53:02   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: ) (WOW64)`

Now, I am having trouble when I got to the point to set up the db connection for the tutorial. The tutorial step to add this to the Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But that doesn't work - and pretty sure it's because the different SQL Server that I am using. Suggestion on how to make this work?

I've tried changing the providerName to "System.Data.SqlClient" and it still doesnt work, and I've tried the following too:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
       name="MusicStoreEntities"
       connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And it still doesnt work with the following exception: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string

Help with setting up this ASP.Net - SQL Server Express 2008 would be greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT

Seems like now I got it working, at least to connect to the db:

Now, obviously the database is empty - the tutorial didnt even say about instantiating the database, other than downloading some asset file for the db "SampeData.cs", and add it to the Global.asax.cs Application_Start method:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MvcMusicStore.Models.SampleData());
```

And now, 2 things:

1. The line above in Application_Start dont seem to be hit when in debug mode (I did try rebuild solution)
2. Now I am getting the following error: *Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.*

I think I am missing instantiating the data in the db - but not sure how / what - the tutorial doesnt say much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have restored a copy of the database to SqlExpress. Once you do that, you should add a Database element to the string with the name of the database you restored it as. A helpful resource for connectionstrings is http://www.connectionstrings.com

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
       name="MusicStoreEntities"
       connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=MusicStoreEntities"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Note that what you have is a link to an .sdf file, which is a SqlCE database. The |DataDirectory| portion is replaced with the location of your App_Data folder in your application.

Comment: Followed the config that you set, and I still get the same "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string" - what does that error mean anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure what that error is. Seems to be related to Entity Framework maybe. You might try 'Integrated Security=True' instead of SSPI.

Comment: Edited my original post - seems like now I am connected to the db

Comment: @tsOverflow - Ok, looks like Entity Framework creates an SSDL file, and in there you will find a configuration for Schema with a ProviderManifestToken. This is probably configured to use SQL CE, so you will need to change it. Something like this <Schema Namespace="OtimizeModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008"> should work.

Comment: I dont see any SSDL file - is it created somewhere?

Comment: @tsOverflow - Looks like I was googling old information. I opened up an edmx file with a text editor, and the Schema tag is in there near the top. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think my problem right now is the Seed method is not being hit so it doesnt populate the data into the db

Comment: @NerdFury: Thanks for the help with the connection String, i am just going to create a new Question for the Seed as it's separate issue

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

```
<add name="<CONNECTION NAME>" 
     connectionString="Data Source=<SERVER NAME>;Initial Catalog=<DATABASE>;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<USER ID>;Password=<PASSWORD>;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Replace <...> values with your corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

I can never remember connection strings, I [use this site](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) to figure out what they need to be.